# How can I avoid eating elves when my shark skateboards?

Tags: hungry-shark-evolution

The latest update to **Hungry Shark: Evolution** on Android introduced a new part of the game, the North Pole, for the holidays.

You get there by **eating an elf** in the normal shark world.

The thing is, I absolutely hate the North Pole - it's annoying to play and aesthetically displeasing (and I don't like hurting cute little penguins either).

Is there a way to make elves inedible so I never get to North Pole?

Barring that, **how can I avoid eating them**, when they are stuck in the middle of normal beach-goers and it's basically impossible to maneuver my shark to miss them when land-crawling (and doubly so when I'm speed-land-moving on a skateboard add-on).

Answer (score -1):

The method I use would be to either eat regular fish in the deep or just eat at the otherside of a beach where the elf isn't.
If the elf is in the middle just swim away until it leaves

Comment: Elves never leave. They just hang out there. And "other side" approach is kind of hard when you're at speed

Comment: Why do you hate eating penguins so much?